# CentOS - semanage - Delete range of ports

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

Surprisingly, could not find any clear information on how to delete a range of ports by way of `semanage port`. Here is a list of permutations I tried:

```
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp 0-60000
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp [1-60000]
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp 1,60000
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp 1-60000
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp 1 60000
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp 1,60000
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp <60000
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp '1-60000'
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp '1,60000'
semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp 1000-10000
```

The help message wasn't clear on how to indicate a range:

```
root@service1 /etc/yum/pluginconf.d # -> semanage -h
/usr/sbin/semanage: 
semanage [ -S store ] -i [ input_file | - ]
semanage [ -S store ] -o [ output_file | - ]

semanage login -{a|d|m|l|D|E} [-nrs] login_name | %groupname
semanage user -{a|d|m|l|D|E} [-LnrRP] selinux_name
semanage port -{a|d|m|l|D|E} [-nrt] [ -p proto ] port | port_range
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well that was impressive, you made me go to source code to find an answer. You did stumble across the proper way to define a range with your first try: two numbers must be separated by a hyphen.

What's hanging you up is this:

```
(rc, exists) = semanage_port_exists(self.sh, k)
if rc < 0:
    raise ValueError(_("Could not check if port %s/%s is defined") % (proto, port))
if not exists:
    raise ValueError(_("Port %s/%s is not defined") % (proto, port))
```

If you specify a range of ports when adding a rule, you must specify **the same range** of ports when deleting a rule. For example:

```
sudo semanage port -l | grep ^http_port_t
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443
```

To delete those, you must call delete once for each port or port range between the commas. They can't be a contiguous range because they weren't defined that way.

Conversely, with this example:

```
mysqld_port_t                  tcp      1186, 3306, 63132-63163
```

You can't individually delete 63132 or 63133. You must specify that exact range.

Example of adding and deleting a range:

```
semanage port --add -t http_port_t -p tcp 8899-8902
semanage port --delete -t http_port_t -p tcp 8899-8902
```

Comment: Wow that seems odd. I would think we could just set a contiguous range and it would delete all ports contained therein. In the interim I passed `-D` which resets the port to default ports. Seems to me that these assignments should be only for ports you want, and not all these default ports. Thanks for the followup, much appreciated.

Comment: @MikePurcell Yeah, it's a bit frustrating. What happens is everything specify turns into a key. Thus, resulting key for any operation must be the same key as was used for the add. Blame it on the underlying kernel API.